# insert div every 2 posts without empty div

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pulling my hair out with this! The following code correctly inserts a div with row as the class every 2 posts. HOwever, when there's an even number of posts, it displays an extra empty div below. Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    $connected = new WP_Query( array(
    'connected_type' => '2-col-module_to_pages',
    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
    'nopaging' => true,
     ) );


 if ($connected->have_posts() ) : while ($connected->have_posts()) : $connected->the_post(); ?>
<div class="tile">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
   <?php $counter++;
  if ($counter % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: you'd need to detect when you're on the LAST item being output, and only output that new div.row if there's more output

Answer (score 0):

By the time you fetched the last post you won't have any more; so you could ask again right before echoing the empty div:

```
$counter++;
if ($counter % 2 == 0 ) 
{
    if ( more_posts() )
    {
        echo '<div class="row"></div>'; // It was </div><div class="row"> which always left an open div
    }
}
```

You can add the `more_posts()` function to WordPress' `functions.php` file.

```
function more_posts() 
{
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count;
}
```

Note: This solution was takeng from WordPress' Codex at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

Comment: Thanks, but this causes a continuous loop all the way down the page??

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. the correct number of posts are being displayed but there's still an empty div at the end??

Comment: Snap! The code was inverted: **</div><div class="row">** will always leave a **div** open. I modified the answer to make it: **<div class="row"></div>**

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't leave an open div. It leaves an empty <div class="row"></div>. Your new solution just makes the issue worse and inserts <div class="row"></div> every 2 posts?

Comment: That is what you wanted according to your question. I am just trying to prevent the empty div blocks if there won't be any posts after. I dare to ask though: what do you need the empty divs for?